# Make OpenSSL server only accept connections from clients that already have the server's public certificate

Tags: c++, openssl

I'm still learning to program in C++ using OpenSSL, and trying to build and application where the client initiates the connections to the server. I have

1. Generated a certificate/key pair using OpenSSL (as .pem)
2. Called the SSL_use_certificate_file/PrivateKey_file in the server's initialization
3. Store the server's certificate with the clien and verify the certificate on client side when trying to connect to server

I noticed that even when I passed an incorrect certificate to the client and (correctly) failed 3., the connection still goes through, and the client and server continue doing whatever they were originally supposed to do.

What I would like to ask is,

1. Is there something wrong with how I'm using the certificate?
2. How can I make it such that the connection will fail if the client does not have the server's certificate?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a design flaw.

The point of a server certificate is to protect the client. If you control the client, you should use the (detected) failure to abort the connection from the client side.

If you *don't* control the client, but need to trust it, you need to use *client* certificates. These are much less common, but definitely allowed in the SSL/TLS protocol underlying HTTPS. The effect of a client certificate is reversed: when the server detects a failure with a client certificate, the server can disconnect.